# Overload resolution works on functions, but not with implicit constructor parameters

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution

This code shows a basic wrapper class for the `__int32` and `bool` type. My intention is to extend basic types with methods and custom operators, etc.

Each class has **one** implicit constructor, allowing to assign an `__int32` to an `Int32` type implicitly. This works well, until there is a function overload accepting **both** `Int32` or `Boolean`.

While a function with the overloads `__int32` and `bool` compiles and works, the function with the classes as overloads results in **Ambiguous calls to overloaded function**.

**My question:** Is there a way to solve this properly, so I can implement wrapper classes for basic types without overload resolution problems and without the need for explicit casts by the caller?

```
class Boolean
{
private:
    bool _Value = false;
public:
    Boolean(bool value)
    {
        _Value = value;
    }
};

class Int32
{
private:
    __int32 _Value = 0;
public:
    Int32(__int32 value)
    {
        _Value = value;
    }
};

void AmbiguousFunc(const Int32 &x) { }
void AmbiguousFunc(const Boolean &x) { }

void NotAmbiguous(__int32 x) { }
void NotAmbiguous(bool x) { }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    AmbiguousFunc(123);         // Ambiguous calls to overloaded function
    AmbiguousFunc((Int32)123);  // works
    NotAmbiguous(123);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All besides the question but: identifiers with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved by the implementation according to the C++ standard. Identifiers containing two subsequent underscores are reserved by the implementation according to the C standard (which is referenced in the C++ standard). Instead of using hte implementation-provided `__int32` type, you should instead `#include <cstdint>` and use `std::int32_t` (or more portably, something like `std::int_least32_t`). Or well, just use plain `int`. You should also initialize members in the constructor member init list.

Comment: In general case, `int` != `__int32`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, given `AmbiguousFunc(123);`, `123` could be converted to `bool` (standard conversion), then converted to `Boolean`(user-defined conversion); which has the same ranking with the user-defined conversion from `123` to `Int32`, then the calling is ambiguous between `AmbiguousFunc(const Int32 &)` and `AmbiguousFunc(const Boolean &)`.

You can change the constructors as template, and restrict them to accept only appropriate types.

```
class Boolean
{
private:
    bool _Value = false;
public:
    // accept bools only; no __int32s
    template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, bool>>* = nullptr>
    Boolean(T value)
    {
        _Value = value;
    }
};

class Int32
{
private:
    __int32 _Value = 0;
public:
    // accept __int32s only; no bools
    template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, __int32>>* = nullptr>
    Int32(T value)
    {
        _Value = value;
    }
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/32xEU3Ek4hLpE4H4)

Comment: `int` is not necessary 32 bits, so `int` -> `std::int32_t` -> `Int32` and `int` -> `bool` -> `Boolean` is still ambiguous.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, we need more control depending on OP's scenario; not only passing `int`, and passing `long`, `short`, ...

Comment: The template approach is really nice! I should definitely read more on templating. Thank's for the hint :)